# Markers not working with google-map-react

Tags: reactjs, api, google-maps, markers

I'm working with the 'google-map-react' library and I have tried all but the markers are not showing up.
I pass the coords to the marker in many ways but none worked. 
Here's my code & repository:

https://github.com/jorginyu/ubica

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import GoogleMapReact from 'google-map-react';

const API_KEY = 'WTFULOOKINAT';

const contacts = [
  { name: 'Spiderman', lat: 41.529616, lng: 2.434130 },
  { name: 'Iron Man', lat: 41.528103, lng: 2.433834 },
  { name: 'Hulk', lat: 41.530192, lng: 2.422994 }
];

const MarkersC = (text ) => <div className="contact">{text}</div>;

export default class MapComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      center: {
        lat: 41.528452,
        lng: 2.434195
      },
      zoom: 18
    }
  }


  render() {
    return (
      // Important! Always set the container height explicitly
      <div className="mt-5" style={{ height: '80vh', width: '100%' }}>
        <GoogleMapReact
          bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: API_KEY }}
          defaultCenter={this.state.center}
          defaultZoom={this.state.zoom}
        >
            {contacts.map((contact,i) => {
            <MarkersC  position={{lat: contact.lat, lng: contact.lng}} text={contact.name} key={i} />
          })}

        </GoogleMapReact>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

What can I do? Thanks for your time :)

Comment: does it showing `Sorry! Something went wrong.`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a formatting problem. I deleted the spaces:

THEN:

```
          {
            contacts.map((contact, i) => 
              <MarkersC lat={contact.lat} lng={contact.lng} text={contact.name} key={i} />
            )
          }
```

NOW:

```
          {
            contacts.map((contact, i) => <MarkersC lat={contact.lat} lng={contact.lng} text={contact.name} key={i} /> )
          }
```

Comment: This helped move on, but now it throws this error: "Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {lat, lng, text, $hover, $getDimensions, $dimensionKey, $geoService, $onMouseAllow, $prerender}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you open the browser's console, you will see an error. The problem is with your `MarkerC` component and how you *try* to get the `text` prop.

The parameter of the component is an object with all properties that are passed to it.

You do not destructure it to get the `text` you simply use the whole parameter and try to display it.

So you need to propertly destructure it as `const MarkersC = ( {text} ) => ..`

---

Instead of

```
const MarkersC = ( text ) => <div className="contact">{text}</div>;
```

it should be

```
const MarkersC = ( {text} ) => <div className="contact">{text}</div>;
```

---

**Update**

Just noticed, the `google-map-react` expect to find `lat` and `lng` properties on the marker. You have wrapped them inside a `position` property so they cannot be found.

So your usage should be

either

```
<MarkersC lat={contact.lat} lng={contact.lng} text={contact.name} key={i} />
```

or spread the whole `contact` object that holds those properties

```
<MarkersC {...contact} key={i} />
```

so that the `lat`,`lng` and `text` are all direct properties of the `MarkersC` component.

Comment: Hi Gabriele, thanks for your time, I have tried this but isn't working, :(

Comment: @Donutworry, just noticed another issue and  update answer (*at the bottom*)

Comment: Yes! I started doing it that way, but didnt work it so I tried the position obj. It's not working :_(

Answer (score 0):

Declaring the object type and referencing directly the value of 'text' on the initial 'const' worked for me:

```
const AnyReactComponent = (text:any) => <div>{text.text}</div>;
```

Answer (score -1):

In your question, you have provided invalid GoogleMap key so it is showing error in console `Google Maps JavaScript API error: InvalidKeyMapError`.

So provide a valid GoogleMap key or blank(const API_KEY = '') for development use only.

In my case with blank API_KEY, it's working fine.

(Your git repo code is different than code you have posted here in StackOverflow.)

Comment: well that's because I solved the problem. I recently closed this question. Thanks anyway Ravi :).